# Error in Gii Code Generator Page

Tags: php, yii, gii, yii-routing

Im trying to access my Yii code generator which is Gii.
but when i browse it using

> http://localhost/mysite/gii/index/

the page says

> **Error 404** 
>   Unable to resolve the request "gii/index".

this is my .htaccess file for url-rewriting

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

and this is my url manager in my config file

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        //pages
        '<view>'=>array('site/page'),
        ),
    ),
```

did i went wrong on something?
the http://localhost/mysite/gii/index/ shows the layout of the gii code generator but showing the Error 404...

thanks

P.S.
I tried also to turn off my URL manager and see if my Gii code generator page will work by default by using this url http://localhost/mysite/index.php?r=gii/default/login
and it works...

Comment: you don't need the index/ at the end... http://localhost/mysite/gii/ should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encounter the same problem with the same configuration I did use this URL
http://localhost/mysite/gii/default/login

^*_*^

Answer (score 0):

use this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and try your URL:

```
http://localhost/mysite/gii/index/
```